# PHP - Merge arrays | Numbers of arrays not known because arrays coming by loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

**Apologies if posted already.**

Struggling with `array_merge` function.
It works fine when we use it like this.

```
    array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

In my case both arrays are from MySQL result.
See the following code for understanding it better.

```
    $getfilelist = 'select * from  fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
    $FILE = $db->query($getfilelist);
     $file_tot = count($FILE);
    for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
    { 
   $artist = explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist']); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,C,D` in second.

    }  
    print_r($artist);
```

This prints something like this.

```
    Array // artist in first row
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => B
             )

    Array // artist in second row
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => C
              array[2] => D
             )
```

I want array should -

```
    Array 
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => B
              array[2] => C
              array[3] => D
             )
```

I tried following code.

```
    $getfilelist = 'select * from  fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
    $FILE = $db->query($getfilelist);
     $file_tot = count($FILE);
    for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
    { 
   $artist = explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist']); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,B,C` in second.

    $merged = array_merge($artist); 
    $unique = array_unique($merged);
    }  
    print_r($unique);
```

Results is

```
     Array 
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => B
             )

    Array 
            (
              array[0] => A
              array[1] => C
              array[2] => D
            )
```

This is not expected result.
In above code, I need something like this -> `array_merge($FILE[0], $FILE[1]);` for get expected result. Can't figure out how to code it.

I know `array_merge` function require two or more array but can't figure out how give both array to `array_merge` function.
Suggest me how to print only `A,B,C,D` in above case. Is I'm missing something? Or this is bad coded script?
Also, can this post may have more better title for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will works for an Album's full info. 
I posted it here for future user.

```
$getfilelist = 'select * from fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
    $FILE = $db->query($getfilelist);
    $file_tot = count($FILE);
    $artist=[];
    $music=[];
    $label=[];
    $lyrics=[];
    for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++) {
    $artist = array_merge($artist,explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist'])); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,C,D` in second. 
    $music = array_merge($music,explode(',', $FILE[$i]['music']));
    $label = array_merge($label,explode(',', $FILE[$i]['label']));
    $lyrics = array_merge($lyrics,explode(',', $FILE[$i]['lyrics']));

    }
     print_r(array_unique($artist));
     print_r(array_unique($music));
     print_r(array_unique($label));
     print_r(array_unique($lyrics));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        $getfilelist = 'select * from  fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
        $FILE = $db->query($getfilelist);
         $file_tot = count($FILE);
         $artist=[];
        for($i=0;$i<$file_tot;$i++)
        { 
      $artist = array_merge($artist,explode(',', $FILE[$i]['artist'])); // Because Artist names saved like this `A,B` in first row and `A,C,D` in second.

        }  
        print_r(array_unique($artist));
```

or

```
    $getfilelist = 'select * from  fileartist fid IN (210,209)'; // fetching two rows
    if($result = $mysqli->query($getfilelist)){
       $artist=[];
       while($FILE = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          array_merge($artist,explode(',', $FILE['artist']));
       }
    }
        print_r(array_unique($artist));
```

Comment: In last line it should be  print_r(array_unique($artist)); or else it will print 2 times "A" in this example

Comment: **Warning:** array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: copy and paste the full code... that's already declared  $artist as empty array like  $artist=[]; before for loop and another code before while loop

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot.